# Static IP Address in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure-application-gateway

Not sure if I understood it correctly , but   why would a static IP address be not supported in an application gateway. Isn't that a constraint on it ?

Answer (score 5):

Static IP is already supported.
The Application Gateway v2 SKU supports static public IP addresses. 
The v1 SKU supports static internal IPs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq

Answer (score 4):

> why would a static IP address be not supported in an application
>   gateway

Application Gateway does not support static public IP addresses, but it does support static internal IPs. Also, the Dynamic IP of Application Gateway does not change on a running gateway. It is changed only when you stop or start the Gateway. It does not change on system failures, OS updates, Azure host updates etc. More details from [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm.md#application-gateways).

> Isn't that a constraint on it?

For more details, you can refer to [overcome the limitation of Application Gateway in assigning Static IP](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ef69ebc9-d82a-4d27-af03-6d596af5719b/overcome-the-limitation-of-application-gateway-in-assigning-static-ip?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork)